# How to do search in Room data base?

Tags: android

I have created a room database, and showed my data in a RecyclerView. I know how to add, delete, deleteAll, update data in room data base, but the problem is I don't know how to perform search in room data base?

I have added a search view in the tool bar. But I don't know how to add Queries in NoteDao and the remaining classes, e.g. in my adpter, MainActivity etc.

Comment: You must provide more detail before expecting a concrete answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're able to show your Room database in the `RecyclerView`, this would mean you should know how to use the `@Query()` tag for fetching your data.

Searching is done using the same `@Query` tag using the `WHERE` keyword.

For example, if you wish to find a specific note:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM notes WHERE id == :id")
public Note getNote(String id)
```

However, that's just the simplest way to use `WHERE`. Frequently, you'll be combining it with other keywords such as `IN`, `LIKE`, or `BETWEEN`.

So for your situation of using a search, you would most likely want to use the `LIKE` keyword, which can query your database for a field that contains parts of its data that matches the search criteria:

For example:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM notes WHERE note_title LIKE :search OR note_message LIKE :search")
public List<Note> getSearchedNote(String search)
```

This would search your database and return a list of Notes that has either a Note Title or a Note Message that contains the search term you want.